# DuplicateMappingException: Table contains physical column name referred to by multiple physical column names

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am getting this error with duplicateMappingException. I want to create a unidirectional mapping. I do not want to use mappedBy . I have a release and a comments table. Release can have multiple comments and comments can appear in multiple releases. So I needed a third table called releases_comments. I modelled it with 2 @OneToMany relationsships. But now I always get this error.

Table [releases_comments] contains physical column name [releases_name] referred to by multiple physical column names: [releases_name], [releasesName]

These are my entities in short:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "releases_comments" )
public class Release_CommentEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "ReleaseEntity.name",nullable = false,insertable=false , updatable=false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_RELEASESCOMMENTS_RELEASES"))
    private String releasesName;

    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "CommentEntity.id",nullable = false,insertable=false , updatable=false,foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_RELEASESCOMMENTS_COMMENTS"))
    private Integer commentsId;



@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class CommentEntity extends  AbstractEntity {

    String comment;

    @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true )
    @JoinColumn(name = "comments_id" , nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_RELEASESCOMMENTS_COMMENTS"))
    private List<Release_CommentEntity> lstRlsComments = new ArrayList<>();



@Entity
@Table(name = "releases",
        indexes = {
                @Index(name = "INDEX_RELEASES_NAME", columnList = "name")}
    )
public class ReleaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "releases_name", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_RELEASESCOMMENTS_RELEASES"))
    private List<Release_CommentEntity> lstRlsComment= new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why u are not using many-to-many relationship here.. in your case if you wanna create a third table then the many-to-many will fits best
`@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "movie_releases", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "release_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"))
    private List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>();`
this will automatically create a new third table and this method is bit professional than one-to-many

Comment: ok thanks :)  But still I am wondering what is wrong about my first approach. And I already have a third table. Should I delete that if I use manyTomany ?

Comment: if you use many-to-many then u dont have to create another table, the table will be create automatically for u